# I can't log out.

Tags: bug, status-norepro, user-interface

I choose "log out" from the menu and I get an error message.  Apparently one cannot log out today.

Comment: You are not supposed to log out on this site. :-) [Same here.]

Comment: You can log out any time you like but you can never leave.

Comment: Is this still happening? If all fails, you can log out by clearing the math.stackexchange.com cookies on your browser.

Comment: @Oded : It was back to normal the next day.

Comment: OK - thanks for reporting :)